# What datatype is best for store and easily retrieve pairs [(name,number)] with duplicates in Redis?

Tags: python, redis

I need to save list of tuples like `[ ('name1', number1), ('name2', number2), ]` into Redis.
At the same time there may be complete duplicates among the records (that is, both **name** and **number** may coincide) and duplicates must be saved too.
Also it should be possible to select records by the range of **number**s.
I use a sorted set for this task for now with **number** as the score, so that I can easily get the range of **number**s by `ZRANGEBYSCORE`. To be able to save duplicates, I add the generated id to the **name**. It turns out a dictionary like this before inserting into Redis:

```
{
'id1:name1': number1,
'id2:name2': number2,
}
```

Am I doing something stupidly wrong and there are more suitable data types in Redis for my task?